# React build for static server gives 404 error

Tags: node.js, reactjs, serve

I have a `React` app which runs fine locally but when I try to build it on the static `Node` server `serve` ([npm serve](https://www.npmjs.com/package/serve)) using

```
serve -s build
```

the server returns a `404 The requested path could not be found` page. My understanding is the issue has to do with the fact I am using `BrowserRouter` in the application. I put a `.htaccess` file in the root directory with the following code but it did not solve the issue.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
  RewriteRule . /index.html [L]

</IfModule>
```

One suggestion I saw for a `Node` environment follows but I don't understand where to put the code.

```
app.get('*', function (req, res) {
  res.send('index_path')
})
```

My index.js file is as follows.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import { Route, Switch, BrowserRouter as Router } from 'react-router-dom';
import App from './App';
import Service from './javascript/Service';
import { PageNotFound } from './PageNotFound';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';

const routing = (
    <Router>
        <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/" component={App} />
            <Route path="/Service/:serviceName" component={Service} />
            <Route component={PageNotFound} />
        </Switch>
    </Router>    
);

ReactDOM.render(routing, document.getElementById('root'));

serviceWorker.unregister();
```

Answer (score -2):

you should first build your project with

```bash
npm run build (or yarn)
```

next install `serve`

```bash
npm install -g serve
```

and then run this code

```bash
serve -s build
```